# Spigot ignoring first argument of command

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm creating a */home* command for my Minecraft server, but I'm having a bit of trouble getting it to work.  For regular players, they can type */home* to clear their inventories, switch to adventure mode and go to spawn (which works).  And for admins, what's supposed to happen is they can type */home op* to go to the admin base, or type */home spawn* to go to spawn.  If they don't give an argument, it will default to the admin base.  All of this works except for the fact that any argument in the home command bring an admin to the admin base, even */home spawn*.  I'm suspecting that the argument is being completely ignored, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
package com.epizy.alephnull.homecommand;

import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.GameMode;
import com.epizy.alephnull.homecommand.Main;

public class Home implements CommandExecutor {

    public Home(Main main)
    {
        main.getCommand("home").setExecutor(this);
    }

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args) {
        if (!(sender instanceof Player))
        {
            sender.sendMessage("You must be a player to execute this command.");
            return true;
        }
        Player temp = (Player)sender;
        if (temp.isOp())
        {
            if (args.length == 0)
            {
                temp.teleport(new Location(Bukkit.getServer().getWorld("world"), 0, 218, 0));
                return true;
            }
            else if (args[0] == "op")
            {
                temp.teleport(new Location(Bukkit.getServer().getWorld("world"), 0, 218, 0));
                return true;
            }
            else if (args[0] == "spawn")
            {
                temp.teleport(new Location(Bukkit.getServer().getWorld("world"), 0, 250, 0));
                return true;
            }

        }
        else
        {

            temp.setGameMode(GameMode.ADVENTURE);
            temp.getInventory().clear();
            temp.updateInventory();
            temp.teleport(new Location(Bukkit.getServer().getWorld("world"), 0, 250, 0));
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Strings should be compared with `equals` not `==`

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Wow, it worked!  Thanks, I'll keep that rule in mind when using strings in Java from now on.